# Unable to get the Identity ID after logging in via Facebook using Cognito

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I want to integrate AWS Cognito into my mobile application and use primarily Facebook and Google logins and once the user logs in he can upload/download files from S3 and interact with the DynamoDB as well. I also want the cognitoID for a particular user to be the primary key in the DynamoDB to recognize each user. 
Firstly, is this a good idea, to keep the cognitoID(IdentityID) for a user to recognize each user globally?

Secondly, when I try to get the identity ID using getIdentityID from the sharedInstance, more or less in the lines of following

```
// Retrieve your Amazon Cognito ID
credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continueWithBlock { (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
if (task.error != nil) {
print("Error: " + task.error.localizedDescription)
}
else {
// the task result will contain the identity id
let cognitoId = task.result
}
return nil
}
```

I do not get the needed IdentityID, instead I get a nil, and hence cannot persist.
Am I missing something? 
Please let me know if you need further info.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't intend to merge logins, that should be absolutely safe. Once you've authenticated, the only time the identity could change is when a login is merged. When it is, it would still be possible to manage with a hook you build that moves data from the old identity id to the new one.

That looks fine to me (it's exactly the example starting code). Per [the Cognito docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html), getIdentityId is an asynchronous call. If an identity ID is already set on your provider, you can call credentialsProvider.identityId to retrieve that identity, which is cached locally. However, if an identity ID is not set on your provider, calling credentialsProvider.identityId will return nil. I'd guess that your problem is this.

If you're certain that's not the issue, I'd confirm that your client is initialized as exemplified in our docs as well:

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: AWSRegionType.USEast1, identityPoolId: "IDENTITY_POOL_ID")
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

Comment: I use the ClientManager as given in 
[link] (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/blob/master/CognitoSync-Sample/Swift/CognitoSyncDemo/AmazonClientManager.swift)
in my project, and here the above code is present in the function 
initializeClients. 

And to access the identityID in some other viewController I tried both 
AmazonClientManager.sharedInstance.credentialsProvider?.identityId and the one given in my question, both give me nil.

Comment: Try something basic. Initialize the client as described above, call refresh on that client, wait a few seconds, and then check it. Is it set then?